# How to apply a filter to incoming emails with a certain label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Applying a filter to labels can be done to mails already in the inbox (filter> containing words> label:label-wanted) but what about incoming emails? That would be *really* useful, as we can't filter filters, I'm afraid of ending up with a lot of filters doing a lot of specific things.

Answer (score 2):

Filters only ever act in incoming messages. They also seem to be applied in order, so if you've already got a filter applying a label, you *may* be able to use that label in another label.

```
Matches: label:label-wanted keyword
Do this: ...
```

You'll get a warning that a filter using "label:" (and some other criteria won't work), but just ignore that.

As long as a previous filter added the label you wanted, and didn't otherwise make the message ineligible, this *should* work. You'll have to experiment.